# How do I do an "Actual Page" for a pagination REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making a RESTful API with infinite scroll and regular pagination included. SO I wanted to provide [ElementsCount, TotalPages, Skip(or Offset), Limit, hasMoreElements?, "ActualPage"].

I need to calculate the Actual Page, having the "pages, limit and skip numbers"

I tried this: 
As example. I didnt hardcoded the numbers...

```
ElemetsCount = 17
Limit = 4
Pages = 5
Skip = 8

actualPage = skip + limit / pages
```

But when I change the totalElements this formula doesn't work

```
let { limit, skip } = req.query
limit = parseInt(limit) || 10
skip = parseInt(skip) || 0

const elementsCount = await this.db.count() //for example

const pages = Math.ceil(elementsCount / limit)
const actualPage = ((skip + limit) / pages) // this is wrong

const doc = await this.db
doc[0].pagination = { elementsCount, pages, skip, limit, actualPage }
```

Comment: Why do you use the 'Skip' ? A normal behaviour would be to give the page number, no ?

Comment: Well, the page is when you have your element per page established, but I want to have it flexible. I have the solution already: I use page, skip, and limit.